# Using multiple class in one div with images

Tags: html, css

I'm using two classes in one div. The problem I'm having is I have two different `title` divs and each title will have its own image. I cannot figure out why each title will not display its own image. Both images will stack up on the first div, what am I doing wrong?

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/mRRA4/

**CSS**

```css
.title {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  padding: 4px 22px;
}
.icon-img1:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  content: "";
  background: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/366/icomic/24/images.png);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
.icon-img2:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  content: "";
  background: url(http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/753/gnome_desktop/24/gnome_emblem_photos.png);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="title icon-img1">Title 1</div>
<div class="title icon-img2">Title 2 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove all `position`s? And convert `.icon-img2:before` to `.icon-img2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now add `position: relative;` on your `.title` class

**As like this:**

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRRA4/1/)**

Comment: I tried `position: relative;` on the img class but not the title. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can either set `position: relative` in the title class as Rohit suggested or add 32px to the `top` value in the second image class. The reason for this is that `position: absolute` positions based on the next parent element with a position attribute. So both your images were being positioned off the body and so being placed 4px from the top left. Giving title a `position: relative` means that it will be used as the 'anchor' for the child classes.